# Автоматическая загрузка фото в специальную зону

Tags: java, autoload

Доброго времени суток! Пишу бота для одного сайта. На сайте при подаче объявления можно загрузить фото. Для этого есть специальная зона:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Собственно, вопрос: как можно автоматизированно загрузить туда фотографии? Даже если не программно, то на край,  есть ли кликер/автоматический софт, который сможет перетащить фотки из папки туда. (**да, в зону фото можно просто перетащить**)
**P/s** Пробовал этой замечательной штукой, но, к сожалению, она не умеет так - [wildfire.ai](https://wildfire.ai)
**P/s/s** Линк на этот сайт - https://cars.av.by/user/add. Тут подача объявления нужна.

Comment: наверное нужно получить, что отправляется на сервер непосредственно при отправке фото (уже после нажатия на эту кнопку) и сделать такой же запрос из приложения.

Comment: Вот я так тоже думаю... Но там формируется id сразу. Ну, надеюсь, предложат еще варианты, а я пока копаюсь. Кстати, вот тот самый сайт: https://cars.av.by/user/add